# vba application word using as prefix for workbooks

Tags: vba

Could someone explain what is the point of writing `Application.Workbooks.Worksheets()` ... instead of just `Workbooks.Worksheets()`, omitting `Application`?

What additional restrictions does it impose on the `Workbooks` object?

Comment: `Application` is optional and is typically omitted, with no impact on the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: none.

Long answer: it depends.

By fully qualifying `Workbooks`, you're making it absolutely completely unambiguous that `Workbooks` is referring to `Excel.Application.Workbooks`. If you had a class module called `Workbooks` (with a `PredeclaredId=True` attribute), then an unqualified `Workbooks` would be referring to that class module, and if that class module didn't have an `Item` default indexer property that returned a `Workbook` object, it would actually prevent this code from compiling:

```
Debug.Print Workbooks(1).Worksheets(1).Name
```

If you don't have a class module named `Workbooks`, then VBA resolves the above to `Application.Workbooks`.

---

So, *in this case*, it doesn't matter.

It's not always the case - take this code as an example:

```
Range("F12") = 42
```

That's referring to `Application.ActiveSheet.Range`, and it can bite you in the rear end. Unqualified `Range` functions are the source of unquantifiable bugs, because the programmer is assuming what sheet `ActiveSheet` is.

```
Cells(2, 2) = 42
```

Same here. Unqualified usages of `Range` and `Cells`, are *implicit references to the active sheet*, and they're a plague. Avoid them. Code that uses those, usually also feature `Select` and `Activate` - a recipe for disaster, that lots of beginner think is "the right way" because macro-recorded code uses it like it's candy.

Avoid implicit references to the active sheet, and avoid implicit references to the active workbook. Implicit references to the active application though, are probably fine. A tiny wee bit lazy, but fine.

Comment: Thank you very much for such exhaustive answer. It is great. Learned a lot.